# Ionic2 - Alternate way to route without using injected component?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I am building a mobile app and I'd like the user to have the ability to set their starting page via a settings-page. The idea is that the user can select a page from a list of options, the setting gets stored to local-storage and later, when the user logs back in, the user is automatically taken to that page first.

I have a page-service which contains a mapping of Id's to page-components. This is what I use to find the page I want to use when I read in my user's saved start-page data.

My issue is that I have developed a cyclic-dependency that I don't think I can break without finding a way to route in Ionic2 that doesn't involve using the injected component. As far as I can tell, the *only* way routing is achieved in Ionic2 is with the NavController.push(component) or Nav.setRoot(component).

**PageService.ts**

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {HomePage} from "../pages/home/home";
import {SettingsPage} from "../pages/settings/settings";
import {CartPage} from "../pages/cart/cart";

@Injectable()
export class PageService {
    public pages = [
        {
            id: "HOME",
            component: HomePage
        }, {
            id: "SETTINGS",
            component: SettingsPage
        }, {
            id: "CART",
            component: CartPage
        }
    ];

    constructor() {
    }

    getPageById(id: string) {
        return this.pages.find(page => (page.id === id));
    }
}
```

**settings.ts**:

My SettingsPage component has the PageService injected so that it can get access to get the list of pages. *This is where my cyclical dependency occurs*. The SettingsPage is injecting PageService which has a reference to SettingsPage in it.

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import {PageService} from "../../providers/page-service";
import {UserService} from "../../providers/user-service";

@Component({
    selector: "page-settings",
    templateUrl: "settings.html",
})
export class SettingsPage {
    startPages = [];

    constructor(private pageService: PageService, private userService: UserService) {
        this.startPages = this.pageService.getStartPages();
    }
}
```

**settings.html**:

Just a simple list with a card to output the selection.

```
<ion-content padding>
    <ion-list>
        <ion-card padding>
            <ion-card-title>Starting Page</ion-card-title>
            <ion-item>
                <ion-select [(ngModel)]="userService.activeUser.startPage">
                    <ion-option *ngFor="let page of startPages" value="{{page.id}}">
                        {{page.id}}
                    </ion-option>
                </ion-select>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-card>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

...and finally, when the app starts up and I want to automatically go to my start page I execute the following:

```
const startPage = this.pageService.getPageById(this.userService.activeUser.startPage);
this.nav.setRoot(startPage.component);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated answer**

Use forward ref in the SettingsPage constructor..

```
constructor(@Inject(forwardRef(() => PageService)) private pageService: PageService) {
    this.startPages = this.pageService.getStartPages();
}
```

**Old Answer** - not appropriate because angular should be handling the instantiation of services through injection. "new"ing is a bad idea (but it did work).

I changed how the PageService was loaded in the SettingsPage and the cyclical dependency was resolved. I moved the PageService code out of the constructor and put it into the *ngAfterViewInit()* function. Now the PageService is only instantiated when the view is loaded.

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
   this.pageService = new PageService();
   this.startPages = this.pageService.getStartPages();
}
```